# rails jbuilder - just an array of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, jbuilder

i have a controller that returns an array of ActiveRecord objects and a jbuilder view to generate the json (all standard stuff). works great if i want for example an array of hashes.

so for example i have:

```
json.array!(@list) do |l|
    json.( l, :field )
end
```

which returns

```
[
  { "field": "one" },
  { "field": "two" },
  { "field": "three" }
]
```

however, i want just an array of strings; such that my json is

```
[
  "one",
  "two",
  "three"
]
```

whats should my jbuilder file be?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

A bit late but this will work:

```
json.array! @list
```

But consider to use it in a block to create a JSON pair:

```
json.data do
  json.array! @list  
end

# => { "data" : [ "item1", "item2", "item3" ] }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply: i get a 'nil is not a symbol' error when trying either suggestion. however, when i do `json.array! @devices do |d|  json.i d.device end`, it works (however, i have an array of anon hashes with single key 'i' then)

Comment: Just try to create an Array of strings like `@devices.collect { |d| d.device }` and use this array to create the json.

Comment: You can also use pluck like `@devices.pluck :device`

Comment: What if you want to grab things out of an object to put into an array?

Answer (score 6):

If you want Array as a value for some key, this will work:

```
json.some_key [1, 3, 4]
```